# Error while getting struct with Marshal.PtrToStructure in 64bit

Tags: c#, pinvoke

> This happens only in 64 bit,  but code working 32bit OS

I have two lines codes, I can get 1st struct from pointer but my application crashing at second line.

I tried changing variable types (uint to Int64) I can't find any solution.

```
GetChangesBuffer getChangesBuffer = (GetChangesBuffer)Marshal.PtrToStructure(_getChangesBuffer, typeof(GetChangesBuffer));
ChangesBuffer buffer = (ChangesBuffer)Marshal.PtrToStructure(getChangesBuffer.Buffer, typeof(ChangesBuffer)); // App crashing in this point
```

**1st Error in Event Log (Application Error)**

> Faulting application name: ApplicationName.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x50b214c2 Faulting module name: clr.dll, version:
>   4.0.30319.269, time stamp: 0x4ee9d6e1 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x00000000000d2ad3 Faulting process id: 0xb3c Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01cdcb0bf90a0678 Faulting application path:
>   C:\XXXXXXXXX.exe Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll Report Id:
>   3857cdd8-36ff-11e2-ad19-00e04d3a73da

**2nd Error in Event Log (.Net Runtime)**

> Application: ApplicationName.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in
>   the .NET Runtime at IP 000007FEFAD22AD3 (000007FEFAC50000) with exit
>   code 80131506.

**Used structs**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct GetChangesBuffer
    {
        public IntPtr Buffer;
        public IntPtr UserBuffer;
    }

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ChangesBuffer
{
    public uint counter;

    public const int MAXCHANGES_BUF = 20000;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = MAXCHANGES_BUF)]
    public ChangesRecord[] pointrect;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ChangesRecord
{
    public uint type;
    public RECT rect;
    public RECT origrect;
    public Point point;
    public uint color;
    public uint refcolor;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
}
```

Comment: This is not diagnosable from the question when you don't post the native type declarations.

Comment: size of GetChangesBuffer changed at managed side, not sure if the native side structure changed accordingly.

Comment: @HansPassant which declarations missing? I can complete immediately

Comment: @ctopcu The declarations missing are the ones that Hans said. The native types. Also, seeing the native function that you call would be helpful. That's the function with `DllImport`. Show both sides, native and managed.

Comment: public const int MAXCHANGES_BUF = 20000; changes size of your struct like it is a field. Try to remove it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and @HansPassant: if you look at second line; I m trying getting struct from `getChangesBuffer.Buffer` pointer (IntPtr) not from exported function.

Comment: @user629926; I tried your suggestion but didnt work. Thank you

Comment: @ctopcu If your code is 100% managed, why are you doing any of this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didnt say my code is 100% managed, I said **"I m trying getting struct from getChangesBuffer.Buffer pointer (IntPtr) not from exported function"** I got `_getChangesBuffer` from unmanaged part already and its working properly in first row

Comment: Thank you guys, I resolved with @user629926 suggestion + 32bit flag